# Sometimes category method return nil after UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, categories, uicolor

I use simple UIColor category for random color.

```
+ (UIColor *)randomColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0
                       green:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0
                        blue:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0
                       alpha:1.0];
}
```

And I tested this code in viewDidAppear: method.

```
Method method = class_getClassMethod([UIColor class], @selector(randomColor));
NSLog(@"color=%@, method=%d", [UIColor randomColor], (method != NULL));
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0
                    green:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0
                     blue:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0
                    alpha:1.0];
NSLog(@"color=%@", color);
```

---

First time when viewC did appear, it works very well.

```
color=UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.0509804 0.0862745 0.160784 1, method=1
color=UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.784314 0.509804 0.964706 1
```

But after I present UIPickerImageController and cancel it, 
it shows different result.

```
color=(null), method=1
color=UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.254902 0.576471 0.937255 1
```

Why this situation happen?
It is really weird. :(

Comment: Are you using the address book framework in this app?

Comment: No~ I am using MapKit framework.